# Alternate way to run Cucumber without JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, junit4, cucumber-junit

Is there any alternate way to run the cucumber without Junit.

Is that any possible way to run cucumber as a Java application.. like if I create a main() method and control all step definitions over there?

Any help will be awesome

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Cucumber is a testing library so using JUnit seems reasonable.  You can wrap it in a main method and have the main method call JUnit.  But that still involves JUnit.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is out of date. The cucumber docs have this to say, "[Running Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#running-cucumber)

There are several ways to run scenarios with Cucumber-JVM:

- [JUnit Runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#junit-runner)
- [CLI Runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner)
- [Android Runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/android#runner)
- [Third party runners](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#third-party-runners)
  "

Comment: The links are no longer valid. Can you please update them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber JVM can be invoked from command line. So the answer below applies to any Java codes that can be invoked from command line, not just for Cucumber JVM (which is just another Java component/library).

You can invoke any Java **main** method from your own main method (or any other methods) through static method invocation. We just need to simulate how the command line arguments being passed.

So if you are able invoke the Cucumber JVM from command line:

```
java -jar cucumber-jvm.jar cucumber.api.cli.Main --strict --glue com.mycompany.glue --plugin pretty
```

This is an example how you can do that from your own Java code:

```
public class MyMainClass {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        String[] args = new String[] {
            "--strict",
            "--glue",
            "com.mycompany.glue",
            "--plugin",
            "pretty"
        };
        cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Cucumber is just another custom Junit runner.
so can not have cucumber without Junit.

Comment: This is misleading. I have been working with more than 2 rounds of test automation framework based on Cucumber  that can be run from command line, running under Continuous Integration server.
Cucumber itself comes from outside Java world, which knows nothing about JUnit.