# Test run, but: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

When I try:

`java cucumber.api.cli.Main --help`

I get:

> Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main

My configurations are:

[image]

I dont really know what is the problem... My test run successful.

I use gradle and IntelliJ

I hope someone could help me :)

------------edit-----------------

**My build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'CucumberWithSeleniumTest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:2.4.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:2.4.0'
    compileOnly group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.12.2'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.5.3'
    testCompile group: 'net.sourceforge.cobertura', name: 'cobertura', version: '2.1.1'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-html', version: '0.2.7'
    compileOnly group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.6' 
    compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '4.2.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3' 
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

**And my project folder:**

[image]

---------------------------edit2----------------------
**Here:**

> ```
> C:\Users\...\CucumberWithSeleniumTest>gradle cucumber
> ```

```
Task :cucumber
Feature: Reset functionality on login page of Application

  Scenario Outline: Verification of Reset button # src/test/resources/MyTest.feature:3
    Given Open the Firefox and launch the application
    When Enter the <username> and <password>
    Then Reset the credential

    Examples:

  Scenario Outline: Verification of Reset button      # src/test/resources/MyTest.feature:10
    Given Open the Firefox and launch the application # null
    When Enter the User1 and password1                # null
    Then Reset the credential                         # null

  Scenario Outline: Verification of Reset button      # src/test/resources/MyTest.feature:11
    Given Open the Firefox and launch the application # null
    When Enter the User2 and password2                # null
    Then Reset the credential                         # null

  Scenario Outline: Verification of Reset button      # src/test/resources/MyTest.feature:12
    Given Open the Firefox and launch the application # null
    When Enter the User3 and password3                # null
    Then Reset the credential                         # null

3 Scenarios (3 undefined)
9 Steps (9 undefined)
0m0,019s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^Open the Firefox and launch the application$")
public void open_the_Firefox_and_launch_the_application() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^Enter the User(\\d+) and password(\\d+)$")
public void enter_the_User_and_password(int arg1, int arg2) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^Reset the credential$")
public void reset_the_credential() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 21s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: Could you please show us the full folder structure of your project?

Comment: Of course, I edit my question

Comment: Have you tried running `gradle cucumber`?

Comment: I do. You can  see the result after ---edit2---

Comment: When you do `java cucumber.api.cli.Main --help` from the CLI you should also provide a class path.  Try instead to provide `--help` program argument in the dialog.

Comment: only '--help'? Than I get: The command "--help" is either misspelled or
could not be found.

Comment: The `StepDefinition` package needs to be under `src/main/java`

Comment: Why I never done this bevor. (IntelliJ say: Interface cucumber.api.java.en.When, referenced in file Steps.java, will not be accessible in module CucumberWithSeleniumTest_main  Class cucumber.api.PendingException, referenced in file Steps.java, will not be accessible in module CucumberWithSeleniumTest_main  Interface cucumber.api.java.en.Given, referenced in file Steps.java, will not be accessible in module CucumberWithSeleniumTest_main  Interface cucumber.api.java.en.Then, referenced in file Steps.java, will not be accessible in module CucumberWithSeleniumTest_main )

Comment: Why you launching `java cucumber.api.cli.Main` instead of launching **RunTest** class?

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov I see, but how can I run this without junit... That doesnt work

Comment: Ok, you want to run it directly from `cucumber.api.cli.Main`, or just launch?
You can use the first answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739347/alternate-way-to-run-cucumber-without-junit 
You need to create your own class wrapper and programmatically run Cucumber from it.

Comment: I prefer directly with: java cucumber.api.cli.Main --help

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found one problem, I run my test with junit

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

If I change: **args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']** to **args = ['--help']** it works

but without junit I have no idea